# Refactor SQL to avoid duplicate joins

Tags: sql-server, join

I need suggestions on how to re-factor my SQL Server query to improve performance. As you can see I am repeating Joins and would like to avoid it. This is just a snippet of my code so I am not including the `JOIN ON, WHERE` etc.

The task is to display all houses owned by a person in a single row as a concatenated string instead of 1 row for each house owned by a person. the database schema is organized this way that requires me to do multiple joins to get the info I need and unfortunately schema wont change.

```
select   
distinct View1_outer.ID as PersonID  
, stuff
    (  
        (select ', ' + Name  
            from View1 View1_inner  
            inner join View2 View2_inner  
            inner join View3 View3_inner  
            inner join View4 View4_inner   
            where View1_inner.ID = View1_outer.ID  
            for XML path('')  
        )  
    ,1,2,' ') as Houses  
from View1 View1_outer  
inner join View2 View2_outer   
inner join View3 View3_outer  
inner join View4 View4_outer   

where View1_outer.ID = 'XXX'
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Edited to exclude `MySQL` tag since `for XML path` not present in MySQL.

Comment: which view has the `Name` column on it?  That's the only one that needs to be in the inner query (`stuff`)

Comment: @ps2goat - View4 contains the Name column.

Comment: now we just need to know what columns you are joining on.  If you don't need the joins in the outer query, you may not need them on the inner query. It's hard to give an exact answer without knowing the `on` clauses between the different views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of rewriting my initial query. I don't think I need to repeat the joins in my outer query.

select
distinct View1_outer.ID as PersonID
, stuff
    (
        (select ', ' + Name
            from View1 View1_inner
            inner join View2 View2_inner
            inner join View3 View3_inner
            inner join View4 View4_inner
            where View1_inner.ID = View1_outer.ID
            for XML path('')
        )
    ,1,2,' ') as Houses

from View1 View1_outer
where View1_outer.ID = 'XXX'